# haproxy forward client certificate x509

Tags: haproxy

I have configured haproxy to forward client certificate with

> http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-cert          %[ssl_c_der,base64]

is it possible to forward with x.509 (PEM) format? Now it forwards with binary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but it is possible this way:

```
http-request set-header X-SSL-ClientCert          %{+Q}[ssl_c_der,base64]
```